# how could i send a document for signature based on rest calls

Tags: echosign

I am new to echo sign. I want to implement echo sign using REST API. my question is how could i send a document for signature based on rest calls. is there any sample code for sending documents via rest.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much documentation available but you can start from here:
https://secure.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v4#!/agreements/

SOAP documentation seems to be better, giving you a better understanding about the required fields, classes, etc. You can take a look at it here but you'll need to be logged in:
https://secure.echosign.com/public/docs/EchoSignDocumentService21

You can also take a look at these implementations:
https://github.com/nsbucky/echosignv3 
https://github.com/nsbucky/echosign